# I just added some comment on welcome.jsp, spring-petclinic example give me errors. why?

Tags: html, spring, jsp

I build the spring new example spring-petclinic (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/) by Maven.

I change the welcome.jsp to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>


<html lang="en">

<jsp:include page="fragments/headTag.jsp"/>

<body>
<div class="container">
<jsp:include page="fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
<h2><fmt:message key="welcome"/></h2>
<spring:url value="/resources/images/pets.png" htmlEscape="true" var="petsImage"/>
<img src="${petsImage}"/>
       <!--                      <FCK:editor instanceName="${status.expression}"  
                            toolbarSet="Default" width="800" height="600"  >  
                            <jsp:attribute name="value">This is some <strong>sample text</strong>   
                            </jsp:attribute>   
                        </FCK:editor> 
     <iframe src="sampleslist.jsp"   scrolling="no" width="100%" height="100px"></iframe>
    <iframe name="Sample" src="jsp/sample01.jsp" width="100%" height="400px">   </iframe>
-->
<jsp:include page="fragments/footer.jsp"/>

</div>
</body>
```

I just added some comment on welcome.jsp, then the server give 500 error: any body know why? and how to correct the 500 error?

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/spring-petclinic].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp(19,37) jsp:attribute must be the subelement of a standard or custom action
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1116) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1420) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:194) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:360) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:86) [datatables-core-0.8.14.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:72) [datatables-servlet2-0.8.14.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
```

Comment: which is your line # 19?

Comment: did you redeploy after you changed the file?  it is complaining about code that is commented out in your example.  if you did redeploy, you could try deleting the commented out code and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make JSP comment, the correct syntax is:

```
<%-- this is comment, which will be ignored by JSP compiler --%>
```

You used incorrectly `<jsp:attribute>` tag within a standard HTML comment `<!-- -->`.